# TensorFlow Dataset: shuffle before map (map_and_batch)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

The stock example provided by TensorFlow uses `map` before `shuffle`, like such:

```py
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(...)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
```

However, the [performance guide page](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance) and [one of the GitHub issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20059#issuecomment-403179906) suggest that it's better to use `map_and_batch` for performance reasons. But with `shuffle` stuck there in between, I'm not quite sure what to do there. It looks like applying `shuffle` even before `map` and `batch` does the job, like this:

```py
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(..., batch_size=32))
```

I was wondering if this might introduce any problems I might not expect, as opposed to the stock example provided by TensorFlow. I want the two code to do the same thing, but the second one doing it faster; at the same speed at worst.

Answer (score 5):

This might be a case-by-case problem. Several days ago I met a problem that [my computer will freeze when I call dataset.shuffle(180000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325149/tensorflow-when-use-dataset-shuffle180000-computer-will-freeze-what-is-a-b/). It turned out that, if I map() before shuffle(), it will freeze; but if I map() after shuffle(), it will not.

It feels like (at least according to my experience) that when shuffling, tensorflow is probably shuffling the actual tensors in the memory, instead of their reference (or "pointer"). In my case, my files are images with 112x112 pixels and 3 color channels. If I map() before shuffle(), `shuffle(180000)` will shuffle 180000 tensors with 112x112x3 numbers ; but if I shuffle() before map(), `shuffle(180000)` will just shuffle 180000 tensors that each only contains a short string (filename like "abc-001.jpeg").

According to my experience above, without any parallel computation, **if the data you are going to map() is much larger in size than their filename (which is usually the case), then shuffle() before map() should be faster than map() before shuffle().**

**In the stock example, I think it is because the stock data is relatively small in size**. Unlike 112x112x3 numbers in one tensor in my case, each stock datapoint should only have 4 prices(open,close,high,low) and 1 time(year-month-day-hour:min:sec). In this case shuffle() the data won't become an issue.

**To conclude, I think in most cases (where file size > filename size), shuffle() before map() is better.**